# метод save(new Entity()) не сохраняет данные в базе из-за внешнего ключа

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Есть связанные 2-класса сущности.При вызове метода save() выходит ошибка:

```
Aug 05, 2017 11:40:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
Aug 05, 2017 11:41:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`abonents`.`destroyedabonent`, CONSTRAINT `FK_qudbim04avv9lkhb81ckm9ecs` FOREIGN KEY (`abonentdestroyed2_id`) REFERENCES `destroyedabonent2` (`id`))
```

Классы Entity :

```
@Entity
public class DestroyedAbonent {
    @Id
    private String bla;
    private String bla2;
    private String add1;
    private String add2;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="abonentdestroyed2_id")
    private DestroyedAbonent2 abonentDestroyed2;
    //get()...set()...

@Entity
public class DestroyedAbonent2 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String lala;
    private String lala1;
    private String lala2;
    private String lala3;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private DestroyedAbonent DestroyedAbonent;

    //get()...set()...
```

В сервис классе сохраняю вот таким образом :

```
//тут сеттеры.Устанавливаю значения для обьектов....
destroyedAbonent2.setDestroyedAbonent(destroyedAbonent);
destroyedAbonent.setDestroyedAbonent2(destroyedAbonent2);
sessionFactoryLocalDb.getCurrentSession().save(destroyedAbonent);
```

Обязательно ли нужно сетить объекты в друг друга? И кого из них нужно сохранять? Пробовал много вариантов уже и забыл как все делал.Ничего не сохраняется.Помгите пжл.

Comment: У `DestroyedAbonent`  должно быть прописано mappedBy  `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "DestroyedAbonent")` , не понятно, почему поле называется с большой буквы. И `@JoinColumn` не нужен в обоих сущностях.

Comment: @MrFylypenko спасибо.Помогло.Поле с большой буквы просто не заметил.